# You are not logged in.Please log in and try again.(iOS)

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms, facebook-login

I have implemented **Facebook Login** using **OAuth 2.0** in my xamarin.forms application.But when I try to navigate to facebook page it gives following error:

**You are not logged in: You are not logged in.Please log in and try again.**

It works fine with android but not working with ios.

I have searched it but didn't get working solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution:

**Redirect URL should be same ,when you request for Facebook login and in Facebook settings(Valid OAuth Redirect URI's).**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend is testing the app in a staging environment, leave the `iPhone Store ID` field blank and it will allow you to save the iOS platform and test.