# facebook Oauth2 login error "You are not logged in" in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, facebook, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement a facebook login page using `Oauth2` in my xamarin.Forms application but I have the following error on my login page : "*You are not logged in: You are not logged in.Please log in and try again*".

I searched everywhere but I can't find a working solution.

For example i've seen this solution : [You are not logged in.Please log in and try again.(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393964/you-are-not-logged-in-please-log-in-and-try-again-ios)

So I seted the redirect url (in my code) in the parameters :

```
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: "0000", 
            scope: "", 
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth/"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));
```

[image: Facebook developers params]

Then I saw a post saying that in the new version I needed to I add my ios and android platform information in the parameters. But for this part I'm not sure if the informations I entered are correct :

[image: android platform]

[image: android manifest]

So If you can't find any issue in what I posted or if your have an other solution I will be forever greatful I'm stuck on this problem since a while now.

Thanks